# How to set AppBarLayout overlaying the content?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

This is my current XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include layout="@layout/some_layout" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Right now "some_layout" is above the "recycler_view" and scrolls together with it. I want to change it in such way that "some_layout" overlays the recycler view but the scrolling behavior remains (basically both views should be top-aligned when there is no scrolling and "some_layout" should be gone after some scrolling). Is it possible to do with CoordinatorLayout?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, you want the `Appbar` to overlay you content (`RecyclerView`), right?

Though I haven't verified this solution, it's based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34314147/3739837). Let me know if this works.

---

Extend `AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior` by new `MyAppBarScrollingViewBehavior` overriding `onDependentViewChanged()` and modifying `updateOffset()` to `offset = 0`

```
@Override
public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child,
        View dependency) {
    updateOffset(parent, child, dependency);
    return false;
}

private boolean updateOffset(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child,
        View dependency) {
    final CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) dependency
            .getLayoutParams()).getBehavior();
    if (behavior instanceof Behavior) {
        // Offset the child so that it is below the app-bar (with any
        // overlap)
        final int offset = 0;   // CHANGED TO 0
        setTopAndBottomOffset(offset);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Set behavior on RecyclerView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ...
    layout_behavior="MyAppBarScrollingViewBehavior" />
```